# How to display dynamic url pdf using angular2?

Tags: html, angular, pdf, model-binding, angular2-forms

```js
Updated code which is working now . 

component.ts file

import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Pipe, PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute,Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ObjNgFor } from './retailer_information/objNgFor.pipe';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import  {SafePipe} from './retailer_information/url.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'retailer_information',
  templateUrl: './retailerinfo.component.html',
})


export class RetailerInfoComponent {
  public  url = '';
  
  constructor(
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    // private sanitizer:DomSanitizer
  ) {
    // this.model.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(''); 
   }

 ngOnInit() {
      this.url = 'https://blog.mozilla.org/security/files/2015/05/HTTPS-FAQ.pdf';
  }
   
}
```

```html
<!-- side nav:END -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="yellow-banner">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- master-container:START -->
<div class="container master-container container-minh pt-15 pb-15">

    <!-- Form: START-->
    <form (ngSubmit)="formSubmit()" role="form">
        <div class="row form-wrap">

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1>Retailer Information</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 welcome-user-view">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">

                        <img src="app/retailer_information/images/retailer-pic.png" class="media-object img-logo-style" width="45">

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <iframe [src]="url | safe" width="500" height="600" type='application/pdf'></iframe>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block waves-effect waves-light">
                Proceed
            </button>
        <a href="#" class="center-block"> Cancel </a>
    </form>
    <!-- Form: END -->
</div>
```

I am trying to display pdf on html page using angular2. It is working for static url pdf path, but when I am trying to use it dynamically by taking the value from component and then binding it in html, it is giving me an error ? Error is "unsafe value used in a resource URL context" Please help.

```js
component.ts file

import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Pipe, PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute,Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ObjNgFor } from './retailer_information/objNgFor.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'retailer_information'
  styles: [`
  `],
  templateUrl: './retailerinfo.component.html',
})
export class RetailerInfoComponent {
  public model : any = {
    url : 'http://www.attuneww.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/GettingStartedWithAngular2.pdf'
  }

  constructor(
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {

   }


}
```

```html
<!-- side nav:END -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="yellow-banner">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- master-container:START -->
<div class="container master-container container-minh pt-15 pb-15">

    <!-- Form: START-->
    <form (ngSubmit)="formSubmit()" role="form">
        <div class="row form-wrap">

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1>Retailer Information</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 welcome-user-view">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <img src="app/retailer_information/images/retailer-pic.png" class="media-object img-logo-style" width="45">

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <iframe [src]="url"  name="url" [(ngModel)]="model.url" #url="ngModel"
         width="100%" height="500" ngDefaultControl>
</iframe>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block waves-effect waves-light">
                Proceed
            </button>
        <a href="#" class="center-block"> Cancel </a>
    </form>
    <!-- Form: END -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it Working . 
You have to follow this steps.

1. create a file named say pipe.url.ts and paste the below code in it

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

2. After that import this file in your component.ts file.
3. Also import the same file in your module.ts file and declare that SafePipe in the ngModule section.
4. you can look at my updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

`iframe` is not an input control, so you can't use `ngModel`.

> #### [What is `ngModel`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html): it's a directive that
>
> Creates a `FormControl` instance from a domain model and binds it to a
>   form control element.
>
> Creates a `FormControl` instance from a domain model and binds it to a
>   form control element.
>
> The `FormControl` instance will track the value, user interaction, and
>   validation status of the control and keep the view synced with the
>   model. If used within a parent form, the directive will also register
>   itself with the form as a child control.

Comment: Hi Roman, Thanks. But I have also used object tag for this. <object [data]="url" width="100%" height="1000" name="url" [(ngModel)]="model.url" #url="ngModel"
         ngDefaultControl></object>
that also didn't work for me. Would please suggest me how should I proceed with this ?

Comment: you can bind any property to the object or whatever DOM element

Comment: Would you please elaborate ? Its giving me error "unsafe value used in a resource URL context " ?

Comment: Would you please tell me, what changes I need to do in my code ? I know what you are saying, but its giving me error ?

Comment: properties binding works by dot notation, for safe navigation use elvis operator

Comment: Can you please tell me in context of my code ? so that I can properly get what you are trying to say ? dot notation as of what ??

Comment: If you have the `model` object that has a property `url`, then you can access the property via `model.url` or `model['url']` which is equivalent.

Comment: <object [data]="model.url" width="100%" height="1000" name="url" [(ngModel)]="model.url" #url="ngModel"
         ngDefaultControl></object>    Do you mean like this ? Still it is not showing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141819/discussion-between-roman-c-and-geek-kk).